# How can I import a text file into PowerPoint with vba?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am used to doing this type of thing in Word, but the methods for the same sort of thing in PowerPoint are quite different.

I have a network folder with a list of text files in it. I want to be able to click into a text field on a slide and then click an import button on a custom menu. I then select one of the text files in the dialog and that imports the text into the area I have specified.

I have built the custom menu in PowerPoint 2010, and added a few other macros, but I can't work out the methods to use.

Can anyone give me a start?

Here is the code I am playing with:

```
Sub GetTextFromLibrary()

Dim lCurrentView As Long
Dim SlideNum As Integer
Dim Name$
Dim OldName$

'Store the default shape name to reset later
OldName$ = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name
'Now rename the shape to work with it
Name$ = "temp01"

MsgBox "You are on slide: " & _
        OldName$, vbInformation

ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name = Name$

  ' Get the current view type.
  lCurrentView = ActiveWindow.ViewType

  ' Make sure that PowerPoint is in Slide view.
  ' ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideNumber produces an error if
  ' you are using any other view.
  If lCurrentView = ppViewNormal Then
     ' Display the slide number.
     'MsgBox "You are on slide: " & _
        ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideNumber, vbInformation

    SlideNum = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideNumber

    MsgBox "You are on slide: " & _
        SlideNum, vbInformation

' Dim a variable as a specific object type
Dim oShape As Shape

' Set it to "point" to a specific shape:
Set oShape = ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes("temp01")

'Declare a variable as a FileDialog object.
Dim fd As FileDialog
'Declare a variable for the directory path.
Dim directory As String
'Set the directory path
directory = "C:\Documents and Settings\<USER>\Desktop\PitchTemplateLibrary\Quotes"
'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'Declare a variable to contain the path
'of each selected item. Even though the path is aString,
'the variable must be a Variant because For Each...Next
'routines only work with Variants and Objects.
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
With fd
    'Change the initial directory\filename
    .InitialFileName = directory
    'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the user's action.
    'The user pressed the button.
    If .Show = -1 Then

        'Step through each string in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection.
        For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems

Dim fs As Object
Dim f As Object
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(vrtSelectedItem, 1, 0)

' Put the text into the text box
oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = f 'oShape IS EMPTY, BUT CAN"T SEE WHY.

        Next vrtSelectedItem
    'The user pressed Cancel.
    Else
    End If
End With

' Until we release the memory used by oShape
Set oShape = Nothing

ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name = OldName$

  Else
     ' PowerPoint is not in slide view.
     MsgBox "You must be in slide view to run this macro.", _
        vbInformation
  End If


'Set the object variable to Nothing.
Set fd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you could add your code for ms-word as reference. that would help understanding what you are trying to do

Comment: Get the text and put it in a shape, in Powerpoint. Where in Powerpoint do you want text to be added? What is "methods" are different? Post some Word code!

Comment: Hi, I added the working code to give you a better idea of what I am trying to do. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint code to set the text of a TextBox, or other Shape, is:

```
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange _
    = "Hello there"
```

Comment: Thanks AndyG. Take a look at the working code I added to my original question. Your input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> > I want to be able to click into a text field on a slide and then click an import button on a custom menu. I then select one of the text files in the dialog and that imports the text into the area I have specified.

```
' CYA
If Not ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionText Then
  MsgBox "Select some text first"
  Exit Sub
End if

' You might also want to allow for the case where the user has
' selected a rectangle or other shape rather than a text range.
' You could add the text to the shape as well.

With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange
  .TextFrame.Text = "Text you've read from the chosen file"
End With
```